# Embedding twitch in tumblr issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, twitch

I'm currently updating a website for a friend to support on page streaming.
The technology of choice is  twitch, and I'm kind of tied to tumblr for the hosting.

So the issue is this, I wrote the code for embedding twitch, plus some css to meet specifications (he wants a gif of tv static on top of the video player while it's  not loaded). It  works fine in local, but when uploading it  to tumblr I get 9 duplicates of the code I'm uploading.

The HTML is organized with sections and articles, the whole thing (player + gif mask) has thus been put into an article to match the layout and exploit the site's native css/js.

Here is the code I'm trying to upload.

```
<article class="entry fat-TV-container">
<div class="TV-label">

</div>
<div class="media" >
    <div id="twitch-player-mask"  style="position: absolute; height:1rem; width:100%" >
        <img class="test-player-item" src="Content/Static.gif" style="height:500px">
    </div>
    <iframe
            id="fat-TV"
            class="test-player-item"
            src="https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=fatzrh"
            height="300"
            width="100%"
            frameborder="0"
            scrolling="no"
            allowfullscreen="true"
            position="absolute"
    >
    </iframe>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("twitch-player-mask").addEventListener("Twitch.Player.ONLINE", function (){
    var elem= document.getElementById("twitch-player-mask");
    elem.style.display="none";
});
document.getElementById("twitch-player-mask").addEventListener("Twitch.Player.OFFLINE",function (){
    var elem= document.getElementById("twitch-player-mask");
    elem.style.display="initial";
});</script>
```

CSS

```
.player-item {
   object-position: center;
   padding-left: 28.5%;
   padding-right: 28.5%;}

.test-player-item {
   object-position: center;
 }

.fat-TV-container:hover #twitch-player-mask
{
  display: none;
}
```

Do you have any idea about what's wrong with either the code or tumblr?

EDIT: Solved.
For further reference, if somebody stumbles  into  the issue, try putting whatever you're adding to tumblr's html outside the {Block:Posts}{/Block:Posts} tags, since otherwise it's gonna apply the code to all the posts in the page.